# JSON Object to List Box values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON array grabbed using the code below:

```
$.getJSON("somelist.php", function( json ) {
  list = json;
});
```

somelist.php returns the following values:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"John Doe"},{"id":"2","name":"Jane Doe"}]
```

I also have a list box in the same page as shown:

```
  <div id="someid" class="someclass">
    <select id="someotherid" class="someotherclass">
    </select>
  </div>
```

How do I go about inserting the following options to someotherclass, between the select tags?

```
  <option value="1">John Doe</option>
  <option value="2">Jane Doe</option>
```

I have only done this using PHP before and it seems much more complicated to sort through using JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var box = document.getElementById("someotherid");
list.forEach(function(item){
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = item.id;
    opt.innerHTML = item.name;
    box.appendChild(opt);
});
```

Something like this

Comment: This is also what I need, but I'd need to know what is the "item" here? Is it the objected from getJson? Thanks.